# How to get Visual Studio Code to autoscroll the debug console?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm spamming output statments to the debug console, but I have to constantly scroll down to keep up with them. Is there anyway to configure VSC to autoscroll?

I've tried disabling "smart scroll" but it didnt do anything...

Comment: Have you tried to scroll to the very bottom? Terminal sticks to the end unless you scroll it up , then it sticks to the text